# PHP error in wordpress while including custom stylesheet

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

ERROR

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\awesometheme\functions.php on line 5
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  228960  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0013  232064  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php' ) ...\index.php:17
3   0.0021  252584  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-load.php' )   ...\wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0044  263544  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-config.php' ) ...\wp-load.php:37
5   0.0062  420184  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-settings.php' )   ...\wp-config.php:89
```

My code in functions.php is this

```
<?php

function awesome_script_enqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle',get_template_directory_uri() . '/CSS/awesome.css','array()','1.0.0','all')
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','awesom_script_enqueue');
```

I can't understand why is this error coming.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `awesom_script_enqueue` in your `add_action`. It should be `awesome_script_enqueue`

You are also missing a closing `;` at the end of the `wp_enqueue_style` line.

Comment: Thank you so much.